# Spring Conditional Bean creation based on another bean

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-el

I'm trying to find a way to only create a bean if the value of another bean/property is true, using Spring 3.2 and XML configurations.

```
<bean id="isEnabled" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <bean factory-bean="configurationService" factory-method="getBooleanValue">
               <constructor-arg index="0">
                   <util:constant static-field="org.code.ConfigurationKeys.ENABLED"/>
               </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</bean>  

<if isEnabled=true>
   ..... create some beans
</if>
```

I've seen some slightly similar examples using Spring EL but nothing that does this exactly...

Comment: Can you provide more details on the actual use-case ?

Comment: I know it's been a while since your question, but if didn't find the answer yet, maybe the Sprint Profile feature could be the tool for such job.

Comment: Its quite simple to achive it with Spring java config and `@Conditional` annotation. But if xml config is vital you could look at the article: http://robertmaldon.blogspot.ru/2007/04/conditionally-defining-spring-beans.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use profiles.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd" >


   <!-- here goes common beans -->

    <beans profile="Prof_1">
        <import resource="./first-config.xml" />
    </beans>
    <beans profile="Prof_2">
        <import resource="./second-config.xml" />
    </beans>
</beans>
```

One can activate multiple profile at same time or choose not to activate any. To activate there are multiple ways but to programtaically do this we need to add a initializer in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.MyCustomInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

MyCustomInitializer looks like following

```
public class MyCustomInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        try {
            String activeProf;
            // some logic to either read file/env variable/setting to determine which profile to activate
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles( activeProf );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the factory to create the objects when are required and make them lazy.

```
<bean id="second "class="xxx.xxx.Class" lazy-init="true" scope="prototype"/>
```

There is no way to introduce if statement within the spring configuration, profiles could work but at more related to environment not a programmatic configuration.